# How to add files in a folder outside of Xcode project's root folder?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, llvm

I have an Xcode project in this structure:

myproject/
lib/

and the Xcode project sits inside myproject folder.  Without project is a symlink that points to the lib folder.

If I drag files directly from lib into the Xcode project, Xcode is having issue finding the files and gives "file not found" error when building.

Due to current restriction, I won't be able to move lib into myproject.  I also don't have the freedom to move the xcodeproj file outside of myproject.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Move that file to where ever you want, in "Attributes Inspector", click the folder icon:

[image]

then chose the file where you placed to.

The other way is, create files with the same names in "lib" folder, delete those files. And then use the method I said above, point the missing files to your actual files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On my Xcode where your image is highlighted, it shows ../lib/file.m instead of file.m.  This is the cause of the "missing file" issue. I don't know how to fix this other than moving my project file to outside myproject folder (so that lib is a sub folder rather than sibling)

Comment: @Boon I move the file in to lib folder and then relocate it, it shows '../lib/file.m' now and works fine. Maybe I didn't get your question?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any problem with symlinks in Xcode. Have you checked that the link is correct?

Anyway, to move the `lib` you can do this:

- Move the `lib` folder anywhere outside the project directory.
- Then remove the files and groups from Xcode project tree (they'll appear in red).
- Finally, drag the `lib` folder from finder, from its new location, into Xcode project tree. Xcode will show a dialog to add the files, **don't check the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" option**.

Comment: I did this, but got issue with missing file, see my comment for ray.

Comment: Can you post the verbose error message as it appears in the log navigator (opt-8)? After adding the lib folder, are you able to edit the files inside?